# How to put extracted variables (using beanshell post processor) into list

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing, stress-testing

In my test Plan, I extract a list of variables and stock them into a csv file, but I want to stock them into a list and use them in the next HTTP request

How to do it please ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZu78.png)

Comment: Hey Patricia, welcome to SO! Please make sure to read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to receive high quality answers to your query here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to come up with the comprehensive answer without seeing what kind of "list" do you want to generate out of the JMeter Variables.

2 things are obvious:

1. [CSV Data Set Config is initalized **before** beanshell test elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) therefore you cannot use the data generated in beanshell this way.
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) for any form of scripting

If the `list` needs to be something like `[foo, bar, baz]` you can do it like:

```
def list = []

vars.entrySet().each { var ->
    if (var.getKey().startsWith('userID')) {
        list.add(var.getValue())
    }
}

vars.put('myList', list as String)
```

[image]

Once done you can reference the list as `${myList}` where required.